# server.js unable to grab ID from angular controller delete function

Tags: angularjs, controller, crud, mean-stack

I am working with the MEAN stack, currently I am trying to create a simple crud system using contact info. The problem is that my controller will log out the doc ID but when sent to the node server my app.delete function does not see this ID and shoots out a 404 error saying this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
XHR finished loading: DELETE "http://localhost:3000/contactlist/".
```

Here is my controller function for removal:

```
$scope.remove = function(id){
    console.log(id);
    $http.delete('/contactlist/', + id);
};
```

Here is my node server.js file for removal:

```
app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res){
   var id = req.params.id;
   console.log(id);

});
```

Comment: You put a comma after '/contactlist/'. So your concat fails. Use '/contactlist/' + id.

Comment: thank you, guess I have been staring at my own code for too long.